# Kali Linux would no longer boot

Tags: kali-linux

So I installed Kali Linux 2016.2 on a separate HDD. I have 2 hard drives and one is 500gb and the other 250gb.

The 250gb is the one in which I installed Kali, and it is a laptop hard drive I connected through SATA.

I successfully installed Kali on it with a live USB and in BIOS it would show Kali while booting.

But now it only shows UEFI and normal boot option, and Kali doesn't boot in either of them, instead it boot directly to Windows.

What's wrong?

Comment: Check your cable, and check if your laptop hard drive is actually in good condition and is recognized in other PC or laptop.

Comment: @Vylix yes it is

Comment: Can you boot Kali in other computer?

Comment: @Vylix I haven't tried